# How to use CollapsingToolbarLayout above scrollview?

Tags: android, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I want to create this view with the parallax effect for the top banner.

[image]

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_banner"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/vahab_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/vahab_background">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

All the views above the navigation bar are inflated in a fragment. 
I want the whole parallax thing in the home tab only.

Comment: Please post your java code too of handling CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti would you suggest a code to handle it properly ?
I didn't do anything in java. just inflated the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice blog on CoordinateLayout http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: Been there... Done that... I want to know the problem with my code!

Comment: I didn't find out what I was doing wrong... But you solution worked and that's enough for now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. 
Declare this collapsingToolbarLayout instance as global in your java class.

```
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
```

In activity onCreate() Method put below code

```
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_white));
```

Comment: Try my above code and let me know if your facing any issue.

Comment: what is a problem ur facing?